# How to get the following result by truncating data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have Coffeescript file in the following format. I have to generate all the possible combinations using the : :. I have already written the code for combinations. It is working fine. But, somehow the configuration file is changed & I have to modify that code. So, could anyone please help me to solve this problem?

```
abTests:
    productRanking:
      version: 4
      groups: [
        ratio:
          default: 1
          us: 0.90
          me: 0.0
        value: "LessPopularityEPC"
      ,
        ratio:
          default: 0
          us: 0.1
        value: "CtrEpcJob"
      ,
        ratio:
          default: 0
          me: 1.0
        value: "RandomPerVisitor"
      ]
```

I would like to have the data formatted in the following format:

```
productRanking:
  "LessPopularityEPC"
  "CtrEpcJob"
  "RandomPerVisitor"
]
```

I am using the following code here :

```
START_REGEXP = /# AB Tests/
END_REGEXP = /# Routes/
COMMENT_EXP = /#/
COMMA_REGEXP = /,/

START_BLOCK = /\[/
END_BLOCK = /]/


def Automate_AB_tests.abTestParser(input_file,output_file)
  raise "Source File doesn't exist at provided path" unless File.exists?(input_file)

  flag = false #setting default value of flag=FALSE to parse the data between two REGEX

  File.open(output_file, "w") do |ofile| #opening destination file in WRITE mode
    File.foreach(input_file) do |iline| #Reading each lines of source file
      flag = true if iline =~ START_REGEXP 
      ofile.puts(iline.sub("    ", '').sub("value:",'')) if flag && (iline =~ /value/ || iline=~ /,/  || iline =~ /]/) unless (iline =~ COMMENT_EXP or iline =~ COMMA_REGEXP)
      flag = false if iline =~ END_REGEXP
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think that you have to give a bit more info. How are you getting this data?

Comment: Also, your data set has invalid syntax

Comment: @SrdjanPejic  Could you please help me to get the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you want is to take each key under `abTests`, e.g. `ProductRanking`, and return a hash with those keys having the value of the `value` key in their first `group`, then like so:

```
data['abTests'].each_with_object({}) do |(key, testData), resultingHash|
  resultingHash[key] = testData['groups'].first['value']
end
```

However, if that's **not** what you want, then you need to be a bit more clear. Try working through the operations you want to achieve on paper, and break down your thought process step-by-step. The two operations that tend to be most useful when processing list or hash data are `map` and `reduce` (`each_with_object` being a form of reduction). Look through the documentation of [the Enumerable module of Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html) for more info.

Comment: Could you please give me solution if I read this data from a file?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have a ruby hash, which can be rewrite as

```
data = {:abTests=>{:productRanking=>{:version=>4, :groups=>[{:ratio=>{:default=>1, :us=>0.9, :me=>0.0}, :value=>"LessPopularityEPC"}]}}}
```

you can loop over this data hash to get your desired result

for eg:

```
result_hash = {}

data[:abTests].each do |key, value|

    result_hash = {k.to_sym => value[:groups][0][:value]}

    puts result_hash

end

puts result_hash[:productRanking]  //outputs "LessPopularityEPC"
```

Comment: Could you please give me solution if I read this data from a file?